Создать правильный запрос в Clickhouse
Необходимо (Требуется) создать запрос, для вычисления зависимостей иерархических между полями.
Есть два основным поля - GUID и PARENT_GUID.
Необходимо (Требуется) вычислить в дополнительно поле, всю иерархию элемента.
GUID - может быть сам у другого элемента PARENT_GUID. Надо записать всю иерархию строкой в поле от о уровня.
Проблема в том, что нельзя использовать CTE. Решить вопрос можно с помощью SELECT, но есть ли более изящный путь?
Пример ниже.


Вы забыли задать вопрос. "Требуется" - это не вопрос, это задание.

Извиняюсь, если слово требуется вызывает у вас ассоциацию с заданием. Могу ли я использовать слово "Необходимо". Дополнил вопрос.

Уже лучше. Тот блок, который начинается со слова "Проблема" уже похож на формулировку вопроса. Осталось добавить в ваш вопрос вашу попытку решения этой задачи через SELECT в текстовом виде. Проблема была не в конкретном слове, а в том, что кроме задания в вопросе должно быть сформулировано, в чём же у вас сложность и должна быть приведена ваша попытка решения. Тогда это выглядит как "я тут пытался решить, но у меня возникла сложность", а не "мне тут дали задание, решите его за меня".

Проблема в том, что нельзя использовать CTE. Ну используй RAW SQL. А там внутри пусть будет CTE...

Принципиально нельзя использовать CTE, даже внутри RAW.

Отказаться от списка смежности (adjacency list) и применить какой-либо другой способ для хранения иерархии. 1, 2. Тогда можно будет отказаться от CTE.

А если не морочить голову и заглянуть в документацию... Иерархические словари. В CH есть функция dictGetHierarchy.

Спасибо, такого не нашел, задача не является для меня профильной, но в силу обстоятельств полез в ней разбираться. Поглядим в эту сторону.

Иерархический словарь помог, функция dictGetHeirarchy.
Всем большое спасибо за полезные ссылки и документацию.
